# How to find the test statistic when using the hypothesis test?

Tags: statistics, average, standard-deviation, hypothesis-testing

A credit card company wants to test the hypothesis that its account holders spend an average of 100 per month at gasoline stations.  They take a sample of 1000 accounts and find an average spend of 115 with a standard deviation of 41.  Conduct this hypothesis test with a .01 level of significance.  What is the test statistic?

So I did this and got

$(115-100)/(41/\sqrt1000)$ =11.57

That gave me 11.57 but I think that I am doing this incorrectly

I know that I probably need to do something with the .01 level of significance but I am not sure what

Comment: Do not vandalize your question. The only reason to deface it is because you cheated on something.

Comment: Defacing the question is disrespectful to the user who answered. So I'm seconding what the Count said. With the authority of a diamond bearer. Dropping my voice an octave, but sans allegations of cheating. Noobs occasionally do this simply because they think they own the question.  Read the legal fine print available in the Help Center

Comment: I apologize for defacing my question. My true reason for defacing it is because I feel stupid that I was unable to figure this out on my own and felt bad about not realizing what I was doing incorrectly initially. I meant no disrespect to the user that answered the question as I appreciate their help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the significance level to find a cutoff point that you will compare to the value you calculated for the test statistic. The cutoff point you use will depend on whether you are using a one-tailed or two-tailed test. Your book or instructor should provide you will some information about which to use.

You can think of it as follows: "For a 0.01 significance level I reject the null hypothesis if the estimate of the test statistic is greater then A. Is 11.57 greater than A? If yes, I reject the null hypothesis, if not, I *fail to reject* the null hypothesis." You would find the cutoff level A by looking it up in a table (or using a computer program or calculator).

You can find a two-tailed t table [here](http://snobear.colorado.edu/Markw//IntroHydro/12/statistics/testchart.pdf). You give the table the degrees of freedom and the significance level, it gives you the cutoff value.